# Openfire add user using URL

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I am trying create users on openfire using a url link but for some reason I'm getting an error.

I've installed the plugins and  opened the right port, but I'm getting
`RequestNotAuthorised` errors.

This is the link I am referring to:
http://www.nkstream.com:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=bigsecret&username=kafka&password=drowssap&name=franz&email=franz@kafka.com

Comment: secret must be the FIRST parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Go into the Server > Server Settings > User Service and enable the user service. You will also find the secret key there. You will need to replace the "bigscret" in the URL with the secret key found in the area I just specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "User Service" plugin: you can find it in the section plugin on your Openfire server.

Once installed:

```
Server -> Server Settings -> User Service
```

enable 'user service request' and note 'secret key'.

To create new user you can use PHP directly or using php wrapper for the plugin.

If you want you can use directly cURL from command line, it could be usefull for someone:

```
URL="http://<your_server>:<your_port>/plugins/userService/userservice"
PARAMETERS="secret=<yourSecretKey>&type=add&username=<user>&password=<psw>&name=<name>&email=<mail>"

curl ${URL}?${PARAMETERS}
```

If everithing works, you should receive:

```
<result>ok</result>
```

You receive

```
<error>RequestNotAuthorised</error>
```

because **secret** must be the FIRST parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `openfire` so this is a stab in the dark. Based on the [README](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html), `RequestNotAuthorised` is returned if:

- the `secret` does not match
- the requester IP is invalid

Have you set the secret key (`bigsecret`) in the User Service page in the Openfire admin console?

Is there a setting for allowed IPs where you can specify your IP?

Comment: How did you get this working without the request getting redirected to the admin login page? That's what I'm having trouble with right now.